# Can't obtain SSL-cert with lets encrypt

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

```
IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: xx.yy.no
   Type:   connection
   Detail: Fetching
   http://xx.yy.no/.well-known/acme-challenge/UqI5jVJ0wMvjY1xvJsTv3L3c1vKkkIrfwX-j0Gi3O8:
   Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
   your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
   firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
   client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
   that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
```

I can reach the site publicly. So port 80 is obviously open.

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Does the directory `.well-known` exist and does the server software have permissions to access it?

Comment: An ipv6 problem ? https://letsdebug.net/